# Проверка на все checkbox

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox

**Задание в том, что:**
*а)* Если отмечен хотя бы один checkbox, то добавить класс .active
*б)* Если не отмечено ни одно, то удалить класс .active

**Пример:**
Есть блок "автомобильные запчасти" с 8-14 `input[type="checkbox"]`.
Вы выбираете нужные, а потом меняете значения или вообще снимаете все галочки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) {
  $(...).addClass("active");
} else {
  $(...).removeClass("active");
}
```

Comment: .length - это как бы все элементы?!

Comment: @KobetsMatviy это - сколько таких элементов